# PyQt5 QFileDialog does not shows content of the specified directory but always home-directory

Tags: python-3.x, directory, pyqt5, qfiledialog

I designed a window class with a button allowing to select a folder making use of the Qt5 QFileDialog.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class VerificationWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("PATH")
        self.line2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Browse")
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.getPATH)
        layout.addWidget(self.label2, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.line2, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn2, 0, 2)

        self.closebtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Close")
        self.closebtn.clicked.connect(self.close_clicked)
        layout.addWidget(self.closebtn, 2, 0)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def getPATH(self):
        dlg = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(self)
        dlg.setWindowTitle("Test Directory Selection")
        dlg.setFileMode(dlg.FileMode.Directory)
        options = dlg.Options()
        options |= dlg.DontUseNativeDialog

        
        dlg.setDirectory("/home/stefan/ARCHIVE/SPECTRA")
        if dlg.exec():
            fn = dlg.selectedFiles()
        print(fn)
            self.line2.setText(' '.join(fn))

    def close_clicked(self):
        self.close()

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = VerificationWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I expect that when running this code, the main window opens and when clicking the Browse button, the dialog starts showing me the content of the specified directory. This is not happening, I see the list of folders in the home directory, independent of which directory I specify in the setDirectory parameter.

What is going wrong in my code?

Comment: Is the path correct and does it have read permissions for the user that runs the script?

Comment: Yes, in the home directory I can select folders and drill down until the level I want to select.

Comment: So `/my/directory` is actually in your home? Is *that* path correct, and is it absolute? Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: I run the code in PyCharm as a normal user. I assume that PyCharm takes over the rights from me as user. I put as /my/directory /home where I have access but my script keeps referring to the home directory. Indeed I put an absolute path.

Comment: I on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: I see a strange behavior in general.  I set also the Window title but it is not shown.

Comment: Are you sure you're not running a different file?

Comment: Are you sure you're not running a different file? Also, if you run the script *outside* of pycharm, does it work? If it does, try setting the `DontUseNativeDialog` flag for QFileDialog.

Comment: I run the script from the command line and added the DontUseNativeDialog flag but nothing changed. I can start drilling down from the Home directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254272/discussion-between-noste99-and-musicamante).

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to chat now. Please update the code in the question with your current changes, so that somebody else might be able to help you.

Comment: Code updated at 22:23!

Comment: That `options` is completely useless, because you never use it. You could've added `x = 'hello'` and it would have been the same. Either add `dlg.setOptions(options)` or remove that variable and just do `dlg.setOption(dlg.FileMode.Directory)`. Also, your code has an indentation error and would never run like this. Please take your time and always ensure that the *exact* codes you post are actually runnable/reproducible.